# How can I open a navigation drawer with a swipe from the left gesture?

Tags: android, navigation, drawer

I created a navigation drawer but I don't want to use the ActionBar with the hamburger button, I would like to be able to open the navigation drawer with a swiping gesture from the left to the right in every activity.

I also don't understand very well the use of Fragments.
By the way, to create my Navigation drawer I used this youtube video: [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ju837bQOBfg)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by hiding the hamburger button. Set your toolbar navigation icon to null.

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(null);
```